# Can't find element by id in IE

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to use Selenium to do some scraping. The following code works great in the Firefox driver, but not in the IE driver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

username = 'test@example.com'

browser = webdriver.Ie()
browser.wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)

loginpage = 'http://www.facebook.com'
browser.get(loginpage)

browser.find_element_by_id('email').clear()
browser.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(username)
```

Some information:

- Running latest version of Selenium. IE 11 on Windows 10, 64 bit.
- Have tried both the 36 and 64 bit driver version from http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/
- Made recommended changes to registry.
- Specific error produced is `NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == email`
- Have tried setting the wait to 60, which still produces the same error
- Tried the "Compatibility View" trick (Tools > Compatibility View Settings, add site) from another thread to no avail
- Enhanced Protection Mode is disabled

Thanks for any help

Answer (score -1):

Can you try using

```py
browser.execute_script("document.getElementById('email').value='test@test.com'")
```

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with either language to be certain, but I tried `browser.execute_script("document.getElementByid('email').value=test")` and got `WebDriverException: JavaScript error` in return. Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's because the javascript he posted is incorrect, use this instead:

`document.getElementById('email').value='test@test.com'`